# Getting values out of a DataFrame which is in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas DataFrame inside a Dictionary.

```py
online_dict={"current ferm": Werte_df}
```

The DataFrame consists of 5 columns with the headers and an index t
`Messzeit, Baset_2; CO2; CO2_pressure; Base_rate`.

I now want to split this dictionary into multiple dictionaries.

For example I want to have one dictionary called

```py
Base_dict = {'current ferm': Base_df}.
```

Thus I need to extract specific columns from the `Werte_df`

**How can I extract these values and create a new DataFrame?**

Comment: I suggest spedning some time learning the basics of Pandas. You can [read about indexing here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a simple and quick answer the solution is:

if you need 1 column:

```
Base_df = Werte_df['Base_rate']
```

if you would need 2 or more columns:

```
Base_df = Werte_df[['Base_rate', 'Baset_2']]
```

But like has been suggested in the comments you should do some learning about dataframes, as this is very basic. Learning about dataframes will open many more programming possibilities for you.

Comment: The problem is that Werte_df seems unknown.

I created online_dict={"current ferm":Werte_df} within a function in script 1 and imported that function in script 2, so why is Werte_df not known?

Comment: If you are not sure how to access a dataframe inside a dictionary you could simply do `online_dict.get("current ferm")` which could result in your python code in the following line: `werte_df = online_dict.get("current ferm")` and now you can use the selection methodes described above

Comment: @maki You're welcome if you hit the green tick mark, so the answer is accepted. This question will be closed.